# Xcode 7 Code coverage - what does blue progress and grayed out lines mean?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage, xcode7

Within my project after I run the tests I get in my coverage tab:

[image]

Then when I tap on the gray arrow for `distanceTitle()`:

[image]

And for static method `findLocationWithIdentifier()`:

[image]

And for non static method `deliveryInfo()`:

[image]

Now the questions are:

1. `DBLocation.distanceTitle` is fully covered (blue progress bar is fullfilled) - Does it mean 100% coverage for that method?.
2. When I am inside that method, it is grayed out, and on the right side there is number **0**. What does it mean?
3. Why my `findLocationWithIdentifier` method is white, and next to it is number  **70**? Why that function is not grayed out, since it is called such 70 times? Am I wrong?
4. What about static method? I called them within code, but here progress bar is 0% and within code it is white.

What does it mean? How to read following:

- blue progress bar
- grayed out lines
- number next to lines in code
- why static method are no computed to the coverage value?

For me it looks like the values are reversed to the progress bar and moreover it is computed wrong. Am I right or not?

For now I reported a bug to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

To answer Questions 2 and 3, Xcode uses color to tell you what code was executed when running the tests. Xcode highlights code blocks on the right side of the editor. Code that was executed is gray (it's pretty faint), and the number on the right side tells you the number of times it was executed. Code that was not executed is highlighted in red to alert you that it was not executed. Since the code was not executed, the number on the right side is 0.

To answer Question 1, the blue progress bars show the percentage of code coverage. A fully blue bar indicates 100% coverage. Your screenshots are the symptom of a problem/bug in Xcode. The coverage tab says the function distanceTitle() has 100% coverage, but in the editor, distanceTitle() is highlighted in gray.

I have no static methods to test code coverage so I cannot answer Question 4.

Comment: in the new Xcode 7GM, I'm unable to see the source code highlighting inline. All I see are numbers on the side that show the how many Unit Tests have hit that method. How can I get the inline code highlighting to work? I'm running OS X Yosemite

Comment: In the Xcode 7 GM, the highlighting is only on the right edge of the editor. The code isn't highlighted in the editor. Code that wasn't exercised is highlighted red. The highlighting is pretty faint for code that was exercised.

Comment: I wonder why they removed it, it was a useful feature. I hope they bring it back in the final release today